# Create 360 Degree Analysis in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to create a 360-degree analysis in R using ggplot or other similar packages?

Sample data frame below, describing 4 athletes with their speed, strength, skill, stamina and spirit (all between 0 and 5).

```
name <- c('John', 'Sam', 'Anthony', 'Frank')
speed <- c(1.5, 3, 2, 4)
strength <- c(3, 2.2, 4, 4.5)
skill <- c(4, 1, 2.5, 1.4)
stamina <- c(5, 3.3, 2, 3.9)
spirit <- c(3, 4, 1.4, 2)
df <- data.frame(name, speed, strength, skill, stamina, spirit)
df
```

My question is: Is there anything in ggplot or other open source packages, that allows me to create a '360 degree analysis' for each of the athlete?
Forgive my drawings but this is what I wanted to achieve:

[image: 360 degree analysis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This graphical form is often called a **radar plot** (*stars plots* and *spider plots* are similar): you can do this in base R with `?stars`, or in ggplot/tidyverse. (I'm guessing that you want a graphical presentation: normally if someone asked for an "analysis" of these data I would assume they wanted to do some kind of multivariate statistical analysis.)

```r
remotes::install_github("ricardo-bion/ggradar")
library(ggradar)
library(dplyr)
df_scale <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric),scales::rescale))
```

I could have gotten something closer to your example by (1) not rescaling the columns and setting `grid.max` (and possibly other parameters) accordingly; (2) computing the average of the rows.

```r
ggradar(df_scale)
```

[image: radar plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!